# Set default value for field using model method in rails 3

Tags: model, callback, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I have a table called Enrollments and I have a column on that table called last_taken :datetime. I am using rails 3.2

I had a constraint on the database to set this field to Time.now but of course that just set the default to the time of the migration. What I want is to set a default value in the model. Looking on this site the solution seems to be a callback, which I have tried in several forms. This is what is currently not working:

```
after_initialize :set_last_taken

def set_last_taken
  self.last_taken ||= Time.zone.now
end
```

No matter which callback I use (i.e. before_create, before_save) I get a value of nil when I create the field in the console without setting the field. The console always shows something like:

```
1.9.3p194 :052 > Enrollment.create(user_id: 22, course_id: 8)
  (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  Enrollment Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "enrollments" WHERE ("enrollments"."user_id" =       22 AND "enrollments"."course_id" = 8) LIMIT 1
  SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "enrollments" ("course_id", "created_at", "last_taken", "role", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["course_id", 8], ["created_at", Sat, 11 Oct 2014 14:56:53 EEST +03:00], ["last_taken", nil], ["role", "user"], ["updated_at", Sat, 11 Oct 2014 14:56:53 EEST +03:00], ["user_id", 22]]
(0.8ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Enrollment id: 108, user_id: 22, course_id: 8, created_at: "2014-10-11 11:56:53", updated_at: "2014-10-11 11:56:53", role: "user", last_taken: nil>
```

Answer (score 1):

after_initialize should work. Please write this on your after initialize method and check output.

```
 after_initialize :set_last_taken

 def set_last_taken
    logger.debug("@@@@ - After initialize called")
 end
```

Please check your database column type and attr_accessible for this field.

Comment: It seems it works when I do it through the site but not when I use irb. Does irb not fire callbacks?

Comment: Yes it also works on callback. You can just log this to see output on rails console.